# Using Left Function as part of a loop - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a functioning loop and needed to use the LEFT function as part of the conditions set.

```
If Cells(i, 4).Value = "Active" And (Cells(i, 16).Value = "" Or Left(Cells(i, 16), 3).Value = "TBD") Then
```

I hit an error with the above line stating "OBJECT REQUIRED."

This is the full loop:

```
i = 2

For i = 2 To lastrow

'(Left(cellVal, 4) = "Name")

If Cells(i, 4).Value = "Active" And (Cells(i, 16).Value = "" Or Left(Cells(i, 16), 3).Value = "TBD") Then
    Cells(i, 17).Interior.ColorIndex = 12
End If

Next i
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Left(Cells(i, 16), 3).Value
```

should be

```
Left(Cells(i, 16).Value, 3)
```

Comment: @Tim Williams i m totally agree with your answer but i have to suggest something which will make the code more structure - stable. Is it better to declare both workbook & worksheet? For example: **Left(Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 16).Value, 3))**

Comment: @Error1004 - yes it would be better, but I'm not always going to cover "best practices".  Sometimes I just answer the specific question.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for the clarification. You absolutely cover me.